# PIVOT SQL Server Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

Given the following table structure:

```
CrimeID | No_Of_Crimes  |   CrimeDate    | Violence | Robbery | ASB

1            1             22/02/2011         Y          Y      N

2            3             18/02/2011         Y          N      N

3            3             23/02/2011         N          N      Y

4            2             16/02/2011         N          N      Y

5            1             17/02/2011         N          N      Y
```

Is there a chance of producing a result set that looks like this with T-SQL?

```
Category   |  This Week |  Last Week
Violence          1           3
Robbery           1           0
ASB               3           1
```

Where last week shuld be a data less than '20/02/2011' and this week should be greater than or equal to '20/02/2011'

I'm not looking for someone to code this out for me, though a code snippet would be handy :), just some advice on whether this is possible, and how i should go about it with SQL Server.

For info, i'm currently performing all this aggregation using LINQ on the web server, but this requires 19MB being sent over the network every time this request is made. (The table has lots of categories, and > 150,000 rows). I want to make the DB do all the work and only send a small amount of data over the network

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** removed incorrect sql for clarity
**EDIT** Forget the above try the below

```
select * 
from (
select wk, crime, SUM(number) number
from (
    select case when datepart(week, crimedate) = datepart(week, GETDATE()) then 'This Week'
            when datepart(week, crimedate) = datepart(week, GETDATE())-1 then 'Last Week'
            else 'OLDER' end as wk, 
            crimedate, 
            case when violence ='Y' then no_of_crimes else 0 end as violence, 
            case when robbery ='Y' then no_of_crimes else 0 end as robbery, 
            case when asb ='Y' then no_of_crimes else 0 end as asb 
    from crimetable) as src
UNPIVOT
    (number for crime in 
    (violence, robbery, asb)) as pivtab
group by wk, crime
) z
PIVOT
( sum(number)
for wk in ([This Week], [Last Week])
) as pivtab
```

Comment: Thank you, As with my Comment to Lieven above, i'll have to do A UNION ALL on every row in the table? I guess with 150,000 rows i'm probably better off with the solution of doing it all on the web server.

Comment: with the bottom solution you dont need the union at all just add the columns to the unpivot section

Comment: Thanks, Your second answer is a fantastic starter

Comment: This query has an error in testing week(getdate) = week(crimedate) when you have data from multiple years

Comment: Good spot. Easy enough to resolve by including a check against year in the when clause. datepart(week, crimedate) = datepart(week, GETDATE()) AND datepart(year, crimedate) = datepart(year, GETDATE())

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but a solution with an optimal query plan:

Sample data

```
create table crimes(
    CrimeID int, No_Of_Crimes int, CrimeDate datetime,
    Violence char(1), Robbery char(1), ASB char(1));
insert crimes
select 1,1,'20110221','Y','Y','N' union all
select 2,3,'20110218','Y','N','N' union all
select 3,3,'20110223','N','N','Y' union all
select 4,2,'20110216','N','N','Y' union all
select 5,1,'20110217','N','N','Y';
```

Make more data - about 10240 rows in total in addition to the 5 above, each 5 being 2 weeks prior to the previous 5.  Also create an index that will help on `crimedate`.

```
insert crimes
select crimeId+number*5, no_of_Crimes, DATEADD(wk,-number*2,crimedate),
violence, robbery, asb
from crimes, master..spt_values
where type='P'

create index ix_crimedate on crimes(crimedate)
```

From here on, check output of each to see where this is going. Check also the execution plan.

Standard Unpivot to break the categories.

```
select CrimeID, No_Of_Crimes, CrimeDate, Category, YesNo
from crimes
unpivot (YesNo for Category in (Violence,Robbery,ASB)) upv
where YesNo='Y'
```

Notes:

1. The filter on YesNo is actually applied AFTER unpivoting. You can comment it out to see.

Unpivot again, but this time select data only for last week and this week.

```
select CrimeID, No_Of_Crimes, Category,
    Week = sign(datediff(d,CrimeDate,w.firstDayThisWeek)+0.1)
from crimes
unpivot (YesNo for Category in (Violence,Robbery,ASB)) upv
cross join (select DATEADD(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)) w(firstDayThisWeek)
where YesNo='Y'
  and CrimeDate >= w.firstDayThisWeek -7
  and CrimeDate <  w.firstDayThisWeek +7
```

Notes:

1. `(select DATEADD(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)) w(firstDayThisWeek)` makes a single-column table where the column contains the pivotal date for this query, being the first day of the current week (using DATEFIRST setting)
2. The filter on CrimeDate is actually applied on the BASE TABLE prior to unpivoting. Check plan
3. `Sign()` just breaks the data into 3 buckets (-1/0/+1). Adding +0.1 ensures that there are only two buckets -1 and +1.

The final query, pivoting by this/last week

```
select Category, isnull([1],0) ThisWeek, isnull([-1],0) LastWeek
from
(
    select Category, No_Of_Crimes,
        Week = sign(datediff(d,w.firstDayThisWeek,CrimeDate)+0.1)
    from crimes
    unpivot (YesNo for Category in (Violence,Robbery,ASB)) upv
    cross join (select DATEADD(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), -1)) w(firstDayThisWeek)
    where YesNo='Y'
      and CrimeDate >= w.firstDayThisWeek -7
      and CrimeDate <  w.firstDayThisWeek +7
) p
pivot (sum(No_Of_Crimes) for Week in ([-1],[1])) pv
order by Category Desc
```

Output

```
Category  ThisWeek    LastWeek
--------- ----------- -----------
Violence  1           3
Robbery   1           0
ASB       3           3
```

Comment: +1 for more describing text -1 for column names like [-1] ... *smile*

Comment: @Manfred - you do realise that the PIVOT clause uses the `values` from the data right? And that `-1` and `1` are the values themselves from using SIGN()? But I guess that's why there's a _smile_ =p

Comment: I get an "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'values'" error whilst trying to run this query

Comment: @Doozer - changed the VALUES (2008+) syntax to SELECT (sql server 2005 compatible)

Comment: Damn you're Quick! It's not picking up any values for ThisWeek though.

Comment: Ignore that last comment, There were no values in the DB for last week.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
declare @FirstDayOfThisWeek date = '20110220';
select cat.category, 
       ThisWeek = sum(case when cat.CrimeDate >= @FirstDayOfThisWeek
                     then crt.No_of_crimes else 0 end), 
       LastWeek = sum(case when cat.CrimeDate >= @FirstDayOfThisWeek
                     then 0 else crt.No_of_crimes end)
from crimetable crt
cross apply (values 
    ('Violence', crt.Violence),
    ('Robbery', crt.Robbery),
    ('ASB', crt.ASB))
    cat (category, incategory)
where cat.incategory = 'Y'
  and crt.CrimeDate >= @FirstDayOfThisWeek-7
group by cat.category;
```

Comment: +1 `apply` (2005+) and `values syntax` (2008+) ; -1 inconsistency for still manually unpivot/pivot-ing (not using sql-server feature)

Comment: I'm unpivoting manually again after using unpivot for some years! See Itzik Ben-Gans artical in the current SQL Server Magazine. Doing it this way you get multiple unpivoting results with one single scan of the base table... but I agree in this case UNPIVOT would have been possible, too (but: Non-Standard-SQL!)